# With bootstrap v3.3.2, can I place a glyphicon on top of an img element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlapping, glyphicons

I'm trying to position a glyphicon so it sits on top of the center of an img element. I've tried positioning, styling, padding, margins, z-indexes, etc. but the glyph always wants to stay outside the image and refuses to overlap.

Is it possible to place the glyphicon ontop of the img element?

Here is my current html:

```
<div class="prettycircle">
    <img class="img-circle" src="mp3circlew.png" style="width: 160px; height: 140px;"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>
  </div>
```

And my current css, though not all of what I have tried:

```
.prettycircle {
  width: 160px;
}

.prettycircle .glyphicon-usd {
position:relative;
top:2px;
right:-5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this code:**

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="prettycircle">
    <img class="img-circle" src="mp3circlew.png" style="width: 160px; height: 140px;"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd">dvfdvg</span>
  </div
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.prettycircle{
   position: relative;
   width: 160px;
}
.prettycircle .glyphicon-usd {
 left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
}
```

See **[jsfiidle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/ue9tt2sn/)**

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it. It put the glyph outside the top left corner, but the glyph tag was actually overlapping the image. When I tried to move the glyph a little bit over to the right, (tried increments of 1 pixel) it just jumped to outside the top *right* corner, and the glyph itself never went inside the image.

Answer (score 0):

I just read your question , and I am not quite sure this can be a solution but I want give it a try to help you out, You see we can make a image as background property, like

```
background:url('img/img.jpg');
```

And after that we can apply the `<span>` tag as with positions . Please , if it does help . I will be happy .     -- Prio

Comment: Thank you, I did try this method before and the glyph-icon was on top of the image, but the image was skewed and repeating and I still couldn't for the life of me get the glyph to get in the center.